# Как сменить иконку кнопки?

Tags: java, android

Допустим есть кнопка:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/testButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_edit_24" />
```

Нужно сменить icon через java код

```
Button testButton = findViewById(R.id.testButton);
```

При попытке вызвать

```
testButton.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_add_circle_outline_24);
```

пишет:

```
cannot resolve method "setIcon" in Button
```

Comment: Приведите пример того как вы пытались вызвать setIcon и опишите пожалуйста, почему вы считаете что данный метод не работает

Comment: @МихаилРебров `Button testButton = findViewById(R.id.testButton);` При попытке вызвать `testButton.setIcon();` пишет: _cannot resolve method "setIcon" in Button_

Comment: потому что указанного вами метода там нет...

Comment: Ну вот мне нужен другой метод, чтобы поменять иконку

Comment: в сигнатуре  присутствуют параметры, которые определяют данный метод единственным образом...Вы пытаетесь вызвать метод `setIcon` в котором нет параметров, на что Вам компилятор вполне закономерно возражает, потому что он про такой метод ничего не слышал...для него есть методы `setIcon`, в которые тем или иным образом что-то передают, а вы этого сделать не пытаетесь

Comment: как-то так `testButton.setIcon(R.drawable.drawable)`

Comment: получилось?....

Comment: В любом случае пишет _cannot resolve method "setIcon" in Button_

Comment: А что это за атрибут `icon` у `Button` - это работает? `Button` - это просто текст с фоном, картинки в него можно вставлять по четырём сторонам от текста атрибутами `android:drawable<Start|End|Left|Right|Top|Bottom>` и методами `setCompoundDrawablesXXX()`